# Vhdl How Can I reset this signal

Tags: vhdl, reset

I'm trying to send two data to PC according to a counter. I need to send this two data just once, so I'm using a signal called "New_data_s". But my problem is this signal stays "High" too much and the data is being sent more than once. I'm sending "Datafll_s" by the way.

This is a picture of the first simulation: [Sim1](http://oi44.tinypic.com/357ozmt.jpg)

Then I added another signal called "Stop_s" to reset this "New_data_s". Okay it sends the data just once, but this time, I can't reset "Stop_s". Once it goes "High" it stays "High" until I press the button. So I can't send the second data.

This is a picture of the second simulation: [Sim2](http://oi39.tinypic.com/t0lxeb.jpg)

I know if I don't press the button this "ELSIF(Go_s='1' and Go_s_ff='0')Then" condition is not TRUE, so that's why "Stop_s" stays "High" until I press the button. But, I couldn't find a way to do this.

Counter part:

```
IF(Cnt_Spc_P1>15 and Cnt_Spc_P1<=30)Then
    Three_spc_s<='1';
    Seven_spc_s<='0';
ELSIF(Cnt_Spc_P1>30 and Cnt_Spc_P1<50)Then
    Three_spc_s<='0';
    Seven_spc_s<='1';
ELSIF(Cnt_Spc_P1=50)Then  
    Three_spc_s<='0';
    Seven_spc_s<='1';
    Enable_1_s<='0';
    Cnt_Spc_P1<=0;
ELSE
    Three_spc_s<='0';
    Seven_spc_s<='0';
END IF;
```

Main part:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Entity Letters is
Port(
Clk: in std_logic;
Reset: in std_logic;
Dot: in std_logic;
Dash: in std_logic;
Error : out std_logic;
New_data: out std_logic;
three_spc: in std_logic;
seven_spc: in std_logic;
d_out_d: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
d_out_a: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
);
END Letters;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Architecture Letters_a of Letters is
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Type state is (Start, Space, T, E);
Signal current_s: state;
Signal Go_s, Go_s_ff: std_logic:='0';
signal data_d : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0):="1100100";
signal data_a : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0):="00000000";
Signal Error_s, New_data_s : std_logic:='0';
Signal Stop_s : std_logic:='0';
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCESS(Clk, three_spc, seven_spc, current_s, Reset)
BEGIN
    IF(Reset='1')Then
        current_s<=Start;
        data_d<="0000000";
        data_a<="00000000";
        d_out_d<="1100100";
        Error_s<='0';
        New_data_s<='0';    
        Stop_s<='0';
    ELSIF(Rising_Edge(Clk))Then
        IF(three_spc='1')Then
            d_out_d<=data_d;
            d_out_a<=data_a;
            New_data_s<='1';
            Stop_s<='1';
            current_s<=Start;
        ELSIF(seven_spc='1')Then
            current_s<=Space;
            d_out_d<=data_d;
            d_out_a<="00100000";
            New_data_s<='1';
            Stop_s<='1';
            current_s<=Start;
        ELSIF(Go_s='1' and Go_s_ff='0')Then
            Case current_s is
                When Start =>
                New_data_s<='0';
                Stop_s<='0';
                    IF(Dash='1')Then
                        current_s<=T;
                        data_d<="1100100";
                        data_a<="01010100";
                        Error_s<='0';
                    ELSIF(Dot='1')Then
                        current_s<=E;
                        Error_s<='0';
                        data_d<="0000110";
                        data_a<="01000101";
                    END IF;
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
                When T =>                       
                    IF(Dash='1')Then
                        current_s<=M;
                        data_d<="1100100";
                        data_a<="01001101";
                    ELSIF(Dot='1')Then
                        current_s<=N;
                        data_d<="0101011";
                        data_a<="01001110";
                    END IF;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------             
                When E =>
                    IF(Dash='1')Then
                        current_s<=A;
                        data_d<="0001000";
                        data_a<="01000001";
                    ELSIF(Dot='1')Then
                        current_s<=I;
                        data_d<="1111001";
                        data_a<="01001001";
                    END IF;


                When OTHERS =>
                    current_s <= Start;
                    Error_s<='1'; -- Unidentified letter.
                    data_d<="1100100";
                    New_data_s<='0';
                    Stop_s<='0';
            END Case;
        END IF;

    IF(Stop_s='1')Then
        New_data_s<='0';
    END IF;

    END IF; 
END PROCESS;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCESS(Clk, Dot, Dash, Reset)
BEGIN
Go_s<=Dash or Dot;
    IF(Reset='1')Then
        Go_s<='0';
        Go_s_ff<='0';
    ELSIF(Rising_Edge(Clk))Then     
      Go_s_ff<=Go_s;        
   END IF;
END PROCESS;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error<=Error_s;
New_data<=New_data_s;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
END Letters_a;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've declared an enumerated type state and instantiated a signal current_s of type state. The enumerated type includes the literals, (Start, Space, T, E), but you assign literals M, N and A to signal current_s which are not members of the state type. Your compiler should complain about that. Does it?

The fsm included in your code is a bit difficult to follow because state transition code is mixed with output signal logic. So, I've rewritten it and posted it below. My fsm may not exactly represent the functionality you're looking for, however, you can use it as a template. It illustrates how to generate a one clock wide edge detector for the dot and dash signals. It also illustrates how to control the data strobe signal that you were having difficulty switching on and off.

The output logic does not take full advantage of the default signal values that proceed the output logic case statement so that it will be easier for you to see what's happening. However, many of the statements within the case could be eliminated for compactness.

Also, I haven't compiled the code, so you may find a few syntax errors, but the template should be of use to you.

```
-- Note, not all signals are declared here, refer to the posted code for them

Type state_t is (Idle, start_dot, start_dash, E_dot, strobe_3spc_data,
                    wait_1, strobe_7spc_data, wait_2, E_dash);

signal state_snoop : state_t; -- use to monitor state in simulator
signal dash_ff     : std_logic;
signal dash_pulse  : std_logic;
signal dot_ff      : std_logic;
signal dot_pulse   : std_logic;

fsm: process (clk)
    variable current_s : state_t;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if Reset = '1' then
                current_s := Idle;
            else
                case Idle is
                    when Idle =>
                        if dot_pulse = '1' then
                            current_s := start_dot;
                        elsif dash_pulse = '1' then
                            current_s := start_dash;                       
                        end if;

                    -- dot related states ----------------------        
                    when start_dot =>
                        current_s := E_dot;
                    when E_dot =>
                        if three_spc = '1' then
                            current_s := strobe_3spc_data;
                        end if;                        
                    when strobe_3spc_data =>
                        if seven_spc = '1' then -- counter strobe from external source
                            current_s := wait_1;
                        end if;
                    when wait_1 =>
                        if seven_spc = '1' then -- counter strobe from external source
                            current_s := strobe_7spc_data;
                        end if;
                    when strobe_7spc_data =>
                        current_s := wait_2;
                    when wait_2 =>
                        current_s := idle;

                    -- dash related states ----------------------        
                    when start_dash =>
                        current_s := E_dash;
                    when E_dash =>
                        if three_spc = '1' then
                            current_s := strobe_3spc_data;
                        end if;                        
                end case;
            end if;
        end if;
        state_snoop <= current_s; -- monitor state in simulator. variables are hard to monitor

    --------------   outputs decoded from state variable   -------------------
    -- default signal values
        New_data_s <= '0';
        data_d     <= "0000000";  data_a  <= "00000000";  d_out_d <= "0000000";
        Stop_s     <= '0';        Error_s <= '0';

        case current_s is
            when Idle  =>
                data_d     <= "0000000";
                data_a     <= "00000000";
                d_out_d    <= "1100100";
                Error_s    <= '0';
                New_data_s <= '0';    
            when start_dot  => 
                data_d     <= "0000110"; --'ACK'
                data_a     <= "01000101"; -- ascii dash -> 'E'
                Error_s    <= '0'; 
                New_data_s <= '0';
            when E_dot =>
                data_d <= "1111001";
                data_a <= "01001001";                
            when strobe_3spc_data =>
                d_out_d    <= data_d;
                d_out_a    <= data_a;
                New_data_s <= '1';                
            when wait_1 => -- switch data strobe off for first data transmission
                New_data_s <= '0';
            when strobe_7spc_data =>
                d_out_d    <= data_d;
                d_out_a    <= "00100000";
                New_data_s <= '1';
            when wait_2 => -- switch data strobe off for second data transmission
                New_data_s <= '0';
            -- dash related outputs
            when start_dash  => 
                data_d <= "1100100";  --'t'
                data_a <= "01010100"; --'T'
                Error_s    <= '0'; 
                New_data_s <= '0';
            when E_dash =>
                data_d <= "0001000";
                data_a <= "01000001";
            when others => null;
        end case;


        -- rising edge detector for dash and dot input.
        if Reset = '1' then
            dash_pulse <= '0'
        else
            dash_ff    << not(Dash);
            dash_pulse << dash_ff and dash;
        end if;

        if Reset = '1' then
            dot_pulse <= '0'
        else
            dot_ff    << not(dot);
            dot_pulse << dot_ff and dot;
        end if;

end process fsm
```

Comment: `The fsm included in your code is a bit difficult to follow because state transition code is mixed with output signal logic` - personally I find that *easier* to follow that the two process (or one process with separated out code, as you've done) approach...